# Multiple Errors when Running Bun via WSL

Tags: bun

I am trying to install some packages using Bun, but I am running into trouble:

```
$ bun install
error: Failed to initialize network thread: SystemOutdated.
HTTP requests will not work. Please file an issue and run strace().
```

Is there any known fix to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Bun leverages some network features which are only available on newer versions of WSL.  You can usually fix these issues by updating your WSL version:

```
wsl --update
```

And restart your WSL VM:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Also note that Bun only supports WSL2, so you would need to upgrade your WSL version to 2.  See the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install#upgrade-version-from-wsl-1-to-wsl-2) on updating from WSL1 to WSL2.

Furthermore, if you are getting an error for `NotSameFileSystem`, then you need to defer to using a different style for installations.  This can be done by adding the `--backend=copyfile` to the end of your commands.

Comment: @guy_fawkes I have added an update for the `NotSameFileSystem` error.  If you are getting that then please see the updated answer.